# Как в Table View при помощи Segmented Control, можно изменить ячейки используя Core Data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, coredata

Есть Table View and Segmented Control, а так же Core Data в которой хранятся данные. Данные выносятся в таблицу, но при смене сегмента не получается изменить данные в ячейках. Подозреваю что проблема кроется здесь но не могу понять где точно:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger returnValue = 0;

    switch(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            returnValue = self.books.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            returnValue = self.discs.count;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return returnValue;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *book = [self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSManagedObject *disc  = [self.discs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    switch(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:

        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
                                 [book valueForKey:@"title"]]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[book valueForKey:@"category"]];
        break;
    case 1:
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
                                 [disc valueForKey:@"title"]]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[disc valueForKey:@"category"]];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: предположу, что проблема в том, что вы не обрабатываете факт смены текущего сегмента. Т.е. вам надо реагировать на смену сегмента и перегружать таблицу

Comment: Покажите метод изменения segmented control

Comment: Max Mikheyenko, извиняюсь но я ведь обрабатываю смена selectedSegmentIndex.    switch(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            returnValue = self.books.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            returnValue = self.discs.count;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestBook = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Book"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestDisc = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Disc"];

Comment: switch(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
             self.books = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestBook error:nil] mutableCopy];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.discs = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestDisc error:nil] mutableCopy];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Илья Березников, я только так использую Segmented Control:
   switch(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
Разве есть еще какой-то способ делать смену сегмента?

Comment: В каком методе вызвается  [self.tableView reloadData];?

Comment: Igor Kulagin, он вызывается в - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую.

Надо добавить метод обработки (IBAction) смены значения UISegmentedControl.
Внутри метода написать:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Спасибо Maxim Bogdanov, все заработало.